# How to fix strange symbols displayed in cmd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, special-characters, symbols

[image: Symbols]

Hello,
I'm using bash or cmd for Rails console.
I get this weird symbols like <-[1m.
In my tutorial I see the output fine (With spaces and color), and it's difficult to read it in  my cmd...

Can you help me to display those special characters right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Rails on windows is full of problem like this one or more problematic (paperclip). I work on windows, but to do so i use a VM with Ubuntu Linux that run my apps, and the app code is on a samba share. Using this share i edit my code on a network drive using sublime text. I strongly advise you to use any other OS than windows to do rails.

Comment: @Sylario Thanks for your comment. I really want to stay with my OS. I have just started to learn rails and it's not very motivating to know that I will have to change my OS for developing my apps with rails... If you know how to solve this particular problem I would like to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found this wonderful software https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/ and it did solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cmd, run rails and ruby through cygwin, it works better than cmd as cygwin is supposed to bring you a linux environnement on windows. When i tried to do rails on windows it was the most complete tool.

I insist on the fact that you should use a Linux VM to do rails on windows. If you install VMWare player on your windows, you will have a virtual machine running in vmware on your windows desktop. This machine will be connected to you network. I strongly advise you to use this solution, as you will encounter many problems using rails on windows.

I work on windows, and i have a Virtual Ubuntu always launched. My VM share the code via samba and i edit it with sublim text executed in windows. On my second screen i have my VM full screen that display multiple terminals.

Comment: Apparently I get those messages also in Cygwin: http://s24.postimg.org/t03jk78at/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` doesn't understand those color codes.

There is a project to make `cmd` understand them (and add other useful feaures) [here](http://code.google.com/p/clink/). I do not use windows, so I cannot vouch for the quality of it.